# Configuring QGIS 2.18 processing script locations

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-processing, configuration

I've just installed QGIS 2.18. I used the ltr version from from the advanced options of the OSGeo4W network installer. I went to set the folders where I keep my python scripts but when I click 'ok' I get the following error...

Has anyone had anything similar and know how to resolve?

```
An error has occurred while executing Python code: 

RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\gui\ProcessingToolbox.py", line 163, in updateProvider
    item.refresh()
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\gui\ProcessingToolbox.py", line 377, in refresh
    Processing.updateAlgsList()
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 184, in updateAlgsList
    Processing.reloadProvider(p.getName())
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 189, in reloadProvider
    algList.reloadProvider(providerName)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\alglist.py", line 55, in reloadProvider
    p.loadAlgorithms()
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\AlgorithmProvider.py", line 56, in loadAlgorithms
    self._loadAlgorithms()
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\modeler\ModelerAlgorithmProvider.py", line 73, in _loadAlgorithms
    folders = ModelerUtils.modelsFolders()
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\modeler\ModelerUtils.py", line 46, in modelsFolders
    folder = ProcessingConfig.getSetting(ModelerUtils.MODELS_FOLDER)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\ProcessingConfig.py", line 209, in getSetting
    if name in ProcessingConfig.settings.keys():
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp


Python version: 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 2.18.19 Las Palmas, 3a17f72ba5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug [[1](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18807)][[2](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/c83261395476b62f67eace32c78460bdcfd79a8f)] in 2.18.19. You can can downgrade to a previous point release of 2.18, wait for the next point release 2.18.20 or manually make the [changes](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/d8e39fa9940f82ad54c7fcbf9c54fe53405f3ff6) to fix it yourself.

Comment: I am having a similar problem, when I want to save a simple user script in  processing toolbox > scripts > user scripts, at some point I got a message  like this:

Comment: Like that, and now it freezes

Comment: I have 2.18.20 and I have not yet attempted to downgrade, will be still be identified as qgis-ltr? because I had already configured eclipse and if it is not I think I will have to reconfigure it.

Comment: Then I suggest asking a new question here or on the qgis-user list or submitting a bug report with the full exception traceback and description of your qgis install.