# Qgis freezes when attempting to save geoprocessing user script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I have recently installed QGIS 2.18.20 32 bits (QGIS-ltr) on Windows 10 64bits machine. I have a small python script in the following path:

```
C:\PracticaQGisPlugins
```

The script its visible too in the processing toolbox > scripts > user scripts.

While it executes well, when I first tried to save a modification, an error message showed up:

```
An error has occurred while executing Python code:  

RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded  
Traceback (most recent call last):   
    File "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\gui\ProcessingToolbox.py", line 163, in updateProvider
        item.refresh()
   File "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\gui\ProcessingToolbox.py", line 377, in refresh
        Processing.updateAlgsList()
   File "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 184, in updateAlgsList
        Processing.reloadProvider(p.getName())
   File "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 189, in reloadProvider
        algList.reloadProvider(providerName)
   File "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\alglist.py", line 55, in reloadProvider
        p.loadAlgorithms()
   File "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\AlgorithmProvider.py", line 56, in loadAlgorithms
        self._loadAlgorithms()
   File "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\modeler\ModelerOnlyAlgorithmProvider.py", line 53, in _loadAlgorithms
        self.algs = [CalculatorModelerAlgorithm(),
   File "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\GeoAlgorithm.py", line 52, in __init__
        self._icon = QIcon(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/../images/alg.png') 

RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Python version: 2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]  QGIS version: 2.18.20 Las Palmas, e8e15d5b1e 
Python Path: C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python C:/Users/User/.qgis2/python
```

Now, the message is not showing up but QGis freezes everytime I try to save the script.

Is this related to the bug mentioned in the following post, which implies I have to reinstall another older version of QGis?:

[Configuring QGIS 2.18 processing script locations](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282635/configuring-qgis-2-18-processing-script-locations)

What can be done?

Comment: I have to add that more than freezing when saving is freezing when closing the script if there were changes. I also erased the script from the location C:\PracticaQGisPlugins to the recommended location  C:\Users\User\.qgis2\processing and this it is still happening. I also tried to add an installation of qgis-ltr-full, and the same thing.

Comment: That is very similar to, but not exactly the same exception as the [other issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/282635/2856).  Seems like the fix the QGIS devs made wasn't comprehensive enough. I recommend filing a ticket on the [QGIS Issue Tracker](https://issues.qgis.org/issues).

Comment: Ok, I will do that, I was doubting if I could do that considering that the developers may have focused on the new QGis and this could have been addressed or solved.

Comment: QGIS 2.18 is the current long term support release (LTR) so the devs are still making bug fixes.

Comment: I have to inform that yesterday I was trying to add a library to the existing install of OSGEO4W and without intent the software QGIS-LTR was updated to 2.18.21. This problem is not existing anymore. Bravo.